# Is there any repository with old packages of Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

Are old packages of Fedora available somewhere?

Being more specific, I was using 0.20 version of libgit2 from rawhide, but now it has been upgraded to 0.21. I'd still need the old version. Are old versions archived in some other repository?

Answer (score 1):

It's still on [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/) (the Fedora build system) at the moment. The last build of 0.20.0 for rawhide is http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=521518.